# Exception:Thrown: "OpenCV: Seed point is outside of image"

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

i'm going to do a floodfilling in a binary image using emgu with c#. and when i'm executing the project that says "OpenCV: Seed point is outside of image" 
(Error line is CvInvoke.FloodFill()  )

```
 for (int j = 1; j < imgWidth; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < imgHeight; i++)
            {
                if (outPutGrayScaleImg.Data[i, j, 0] == 0)
                {

                    FloodFillType floodtype = FloodFillType.Default;
                    Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity.EightConnected;
                    Point point1 = new Point(i, j);
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    CvInvoke.FloodFill(outPutGrayScaleImg, outpic, point1, new MCvScalar(255), out rect, new MCvScalar(0), new MCvScalar(0), connectivity, floodtype);
                }
            }
        }
```

The Exception is

```
Exception:Thrown: "OpenCV: Seed point is outside of image" (Emgu.CV.Util.CvException)
A Emgu.CV.Util.CvException was thrown: "OpenCV: Seed point is outside of image"
```

Comment: You just swapped coordinates. `Point` ctor accepts `x` and `y` parameters, you're providing `i, j` which are (in your case) swapped (`j` iterates over width, up to `imgWidth` and `i` over height). Swap your loops or build the point with `Point(j, i)`. Note that you can use `Rectangle.Empty` instead of explicitly create a new rectangle (more for clarity than anything else). A good reason to avoid `i` and `j` if another equally clear and short identifier can be used...especially in nested loops. Check also what `outPutGrayScaleImg.Data` expects if you want to swap the loops.